# NSGenericException reason: Unable to install constraint on view

Tags: constraints, swift4

I know there are many threads with the same title and yes I read most of them. And they didn't help to atleast help me figure out what in the world is happening! I received the crashes reported in Crashlytics:

`Unable to install constraint on view. Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view? That's illegal. constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170497ca0 Hello_World.UIButtonSupport:0x106bf1750’HELLO’.top == Hello_World.UIViewSupport:0x106bf2f00.top (active)> view:<UIView: 0x106bcc820; frame = (0 0; 736 330); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x173e3f360>>`

These crashes only reported on iPhone devices (6S+ and 7+). In our app, the `Hello_World.UIButtonSupport:0x106bf1750’HELLO’` will be `uninstalled` for `traits = width:C height:R` I believe that's "portrait" for iPhone devices.

What I don't understand is why the app trying to `install` a constraint on `uninstalled` view?

Notes:

- No constraints are being added or removed programatically, I use `traits` to handle this
- All views and constraints were added in storyboard builder
- No view is being programmatically removed or added, I use `traits` to `install` and `uninstall` views. I supposed this is being handled
  by the system.
- the `UIButtonSupport` and `UIViewSupport` are custom views

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the issue, but it seems that there's a race-condition when the system is *installing* the `Hello_World.UIButtonSupport:0x106bf1750’HELLO’` and its constraints. If the constraints were *installed* while the view is not yet *installed* the app crashes.

To fix this, I have to reconstruct our *storyboard* to *always* installed our views regardless of *traits* then just manipulate the views' constraints as needed to satisfy the design.